# Laravel Route Name based on parameter passed

Tags: php, laravel

This is how my Laravel route is present

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'add-edit-category/{id?}', 'CategoryControlller@addEditCategory')->name('Add/Edit Category');
```

So if I get an ID - then the controller invokes the Edit function else it does create function.

How to do the `->name()` condition so that, if I have a variable I send `->name('Add Category')` and if not `->name('Edit Category')`

Tried Googling, but couldn't seem to find an example for the same.

Comment: you don't do this ... you make 2 different routes for edit and create and name each as you wish ... there is no reason for the name to be "changing" for a single route

Comment: if you still want single route then create common route with same name and in controller method check  whether id exist in request or not .if id exist then its edit or its new one

Answer (score 3):

Just use 2 routes, one with id and one without like:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'add-edit-category', 'CategoryControlller@addEditCategory')->name('Add_Category');
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'add-edit-category/{id}', 'CategoryControlller@addEditCategory')->name('Edit_Category');
```

Comment: Just to confirm, there is no way we can achieve this in a single-liner right. Like they don't have a hidden way to do that.

Comment: @HariharanThiagarajan maybe there is a way, but thats not clean coding/secure coding and not recommendable!

Comment: @HariharanThiagarajan You could make your controller Restful and then use `Route::resource(...)` if you want it to be a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator for this purpose:

Pass flag from add category controller function to blade:

```
$add_catrgory = true;
```

then in blade you can check in this way:

```
href= "{{$add_category == true ? route('Add_Category') : route('Edit_Category', $id ) }}"
```